# Spring security: Method containing AuthenticationManager.authenticate() throwing an exception

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I have a method that uses the `authenticate()` method inside it, what I find confusing is that `AuthenticationManager.authenticate()` throws AuthenticationException  if authentication fails, however the method `authenticateUser`  does not throw any Exception and no compilation error is flaged!

```
@PostMapping("/signin")
    public ResponseEntity<?> authenticateUser(@Valid @RequestBody LoginForm loginRequest){

        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(loginRequest.getUsername(), loginRequest.getPassword()));

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);

    }
```

Comment: because `AuthenticationException` is the `RuntimeException` . Compiler will not check if you handle `RuntimeException` or not. If you want to handle it , you have to catch it by yourself.

Comment: Your controller isn't an `AuthenticationManager` so why should it. next to that it is a runtime exception. Finally I wonder why this controller as that completely bypasses Spring Security and all the checks it does.